# Page Loading TImes

Tags: php, ajax, session, loading, blocking

We have a site where a user logs in and then needs to choose which of their potentially many offices to view data for. We are experiencing a 15 second delay between the start of request for the choose page and the choose page actually displaying and I can't figure out why.

Looking at the network tab I can see the login requests finishing before the highlighted line, and I can see the requests that build the list of practices, etc firing after the highlighted line.

But why is it just sitting there for 15 seconds fetching the document itself?

This is built in php 7, I have implemented session_start(['read_and_close' => true]); to minimize session blocking. Internally on the choose_practice.php page I have implemented start/end time comparison around the session (averages 0.0002 seconds) and also tracked time between starting the request for the list of offices and when a click even is bound to the final list (averages 800ms).

So I can't think of what could be causing this ridiculous delay. Any insight our tips, hints, tricks would be greatly helpful.

[image: From Firefox Developer Console, network tab]

Comment: There is not a lot of hard information here to work with, but you might try searching for "sleep" in the code - hard to think of much else that would cause a constant 15 second delay - maybe someone thought they were putting in a 15 millisecond delay somewhere...

Comment: @wordragon There isn't much to go on at all. There are no sleep, pause, wait, or setTimeout calls in either the login script or the script to choose an office.

The login is javascript and hits a webservice to authenticate and get user info back. This is then passed to a php file to create a session (we are mid transition between php session and using other methods but that isn't slowing it down. Call is done in 73 ms. The page then redirects to choose practice. That's the part that is taking 15 seconds. The redirect. Once there those scripts fire pretty quick. Confusing. :(